# machine learning in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

I am working on vision project using ( c++ and opencv )

I need to classify 5 number of double , so Is there function in opencv to classify vector of double ?

and if not exist like this function , What is the easiest way to classify vector of double in c++ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "classify"?

Comment: I extracted 5 points from the edges of the human body, head and hands and feet and I need to train a neural network in order to identify if the object is a human being or not

Comment: It sounds like you already know what classifier you're using. Do you have a specific problem with the OpenCV documentation? http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html

Answer (score 0):

> I extracted 5 points from the edges of the human body, head and hands
>   and feet and I need to train a neural network in order to identify if
>   the object is a human being or not

For that purpose would be better to use a Viola-Jones classificator, I think. However, OpenCV provides Multi-Layer-Perceptron (`MLP`) which you can easily use for this.
You have to create a big (>1000) training set which contains five doubles for each item. Then you have to use each time 5% or 10% elements of that set to create a test set. 
See Multi-Layer-Perceptron [here](http://www.bytefish.de/pdf/machinelearning.pdf) for more information about theory and implementation.

However I warn you that with such classifier you probably won't get good results as 5 points are probably not sufficient and you may have many false positives.